# How to get data of a table filled from a text file with csv format in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the data I get from the bulk import and I have in a table called Drinks:

```
| Descrip       |  10/02/20 07   |  17/02/20 08  |  24/02/20 09 |
| SL AGUA       |     NULL       |     NULL      |     2.861    |
| ALHAMBRA IPA  |     350        |     NULL      |     NULL     |
| Carlsberg     |     800        |     2.800     |     2.800    |
| CASIMIRO MH   |     NULL       |      55       |     NULL     |
```

I need to do a query to obtain the data like this:

```
| SL AGUA       |      20      |    09    |   2861   |
| ALHAMBRA IPA  |      20      |    07    |    350   |
| Carlsberg     |      20      |    07    |    800   |
| Carlsberg     |      20      |    08    |   2800   |
| Carlsberg     |      20      |    09    |   2800   |
| CASIMIRO MH   |      20      |    08    |     55   |
```

The first row has data like header (Descrip) but has also data I need like date and number of the week.

Is it possible to do what I need? Thanks.

Comment: You "forgot" to add column names to the second table....

Comment: All are data from a table, I have info like the first example and I want a query to get the second example. Columns can be col1, col2, col3, and col4.

Comment: Try [Import Flat File to SQL Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-flat-file-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15) or search SO for something like `ms sql import text file to table`, and share what you tried to import te text file.

Comment: I can not do it manually, has to be dynamic

Comment: Does the input file always have four columns? or does it just keep adding columns as weeks go by? Do you get 53 columns at the end of the year then it goes back to to two columns in the first week of January? This is _primarily_ about managing the input file format. Once it's in the database it's all pretty straightforward. Please edit the question and explain about the import file format in detail.

Comment: the number of columns is always the same, is invariable

Answer (score 0):

Load the data into a staging table, with columns from the first row.

Then unpivot, I would recommend using `apply`:

```
select s.descrip, v.col1, vol2, v.val
from staging s cross apply
     (values ([10/02/20 07], 20, 7),
             ([10/02/20 08], 20, 8),
             ([10/02/20 09], 20, 9)
     ) v(val, col1, col2)
where v.val is not null;  -- or perhaps v.val <> ''
```

Comment: But here,  values ([10/02/20 07], 20, 7),
             ([10/02/20 08], 20, 8),
             ([10/02/20 09], 20, 9)  you are writing the values by hand

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below step:

1. Table creation & insert Data

---

```
create table Drinks
(
    Head1 nvarchar(100),
    Head2 nvarchar(100),
    Head3 nvarchar(100),
    Head4 nvarchar(100)
)

insert into Drinks values('Descrip','10/02/20 07','17/02/20 08','24/02/20 09'),
                    ('SL AGUA',NULL,NULL,'2.861'),
                    ('ALHAMBRA IPA','350',NULL, NULL),
                    ('Carlsberg','800','2.800','2.800'),
                    ('CASIMIRO MH',NULL,'55',NULL)
```

2. Result Query

---

```
;with tempCTE
as (
select head1,head2,head3,head4,
head5=(case when head2 is not null then head5 else '' end) ,
head6=(case when head3 is not null then head6 else '' end) ,
head7=(case when head4 is not null then head7 else '' end) 
from Drinks
cross apply (
    select  
    head5=right(Head2,2) + '|' + substring(Head2,7,2),
    head6=right(Head3,2)+'|'+substring(Head3,7,2),
    head7=right(Head4,2)+'|'+substring(Head4,7,2) 
     from Drinks
    where head1='Descrip'
) as tbl
cross apply (
        select 1 slno union select 2
) as tbl2
where head1<>'Descrip'

), resultCTE
 as
(
    select distinct head1,SplitHead1=left(head5,2),SplitHead2=right(head5,2),head2 from tempCTE where head2 is not null
    union
    select distinct head1,left(head6,2) ,right(head6,2),head3 from tempCTE where head3 is not null
    union
    select distinct head1,left(head7,2),right(head7,2),head4 from tempCTE where head4 is not null
)
select * from resultCTE
```

---

[image: Output]

[Fiddle DB Output](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac2d231933be8c8f65298d5c0cc82fa1)

Comment: it works perfect but today have told me that the columns with dates can be between 1 and 12. This will be a parameter at the beginning. Is it possible to do that without lot of changes? Can you help me?

Comment: Is the parameter is dynamic column count in the input table?

Comment: Do not worry @Balamurugan, the problem is resolved. Thanks for your answer